# A few basic Counting Problems

Tags: combinatorics

I don't know if I got these correct. Can someone check for me?

1. How many ways are there to roll a sum of 7 with three standard 6-faced die?
   There is: 
   1,1,5
   1,2,4
   1,3,3
   1.4.2
   1,5,1
   2,1,4
   2,2,3
   2,3,2
   2,3,1
   3,1,3
   3,2,2
   3,3,1
   4,1,2
   4,2,1
   5,1,1
   **15????**

2. Uncle Henry has 10 one dollar bills to distribute to his 5 nieces and nephews. How many ways are there to distribute the money?
He can give 10 to one niece/nephew and 10 to the others, **5** ways to do this.
He can give 9 to one niece/nephew, 1 to another, and 0 to the rest. **20** ways to do this.
He can give 8 to one niece/nephew, 1 to 2 different nieces/nephews, and 0 to the rest. **60** ways to do this.
He can give 8 to one niece/nephew,2 to another, and 0 to the rest **20** ways to do this. 

I kept doing this and finally got **6825**

3. In how many ways can three identical rattles be given to two different babies?
   0,3
   1,2
   2,1
   3,0
   **4**?
4. A particular convex polygon with seven sides has exactly one right angle. How many diagonals does this polygon have?
   I'm lost on this one.
5. Each of the numbers 1 through 10 are placed in a bag and drawn at random with replacement. How many ways can three numbers be drawn whose sum is 13?
   1,2,10
   1,3,9
   1,4,8
   1,5,7
   1,6,6
   1,7,5
   1,8,4
   1,9,3
   1,10,2
   9 ways for this, then 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 for the other ones. **45**?
6. How many diagonals does a seven sided regualar polygon have?

   Also lost on this
7. Less that 50 people are at a party. Each person shakes everyone else's hand. IF there is an odd number of total handshakes at the party, what is that largest number of people that could be at the party?
   **49**?

   That's the largest perfect square less than 50...

And thats it

Comment: Why no answers and a downvote?

Comment: 1) yes, it is also $\binom{6}{2}$, see Stars and Bars, Wikipedia; 2) Wrong numerical answer, to make things easy use Stars and Bars; 3) Sure, could also use Stars and Bars, but would be overkill; 4) There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ vertices, but $7$ of these choices give sides not diagonals, so $\binom{7}{2}-7$.  Or else draw a picture and count. Or else out of each vertex there are $4$, but $4\times 7$ double-counts.  May look at others later.

Comment: (Cont) 5) I think order is intended to count.  If order does not count, then the list with smallest element $2$ is a lot shorter, $2,2,9$; $2,3,8$; $2,4,7$; $2,5,6$, and the total is a lot less than $45$. If order counts, you can make a list where order does not count, and beside each write down the number of permutations, and add up. Or else we can do a modified Stars and Bars, taking account of the fact that $1,1,11$ and its relatives are not allowed. 6) We have seen this already. 7) It is $47$. The number of handshakes is $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Note that $n=49$ gives even number.

Comment: Please note that in general putting several questions in one post is likely to result in the post being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 6) note that the number of diagonal for a $n$ sided polygon is $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$.